# Digit at the unit place of the integral part of the number $\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{19}+\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{82}$

Tags: combinatorics

The Digit at the unit place of the integral part of the number $\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{19}+\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{82}$ is

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let $\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{19} = I_{1}+f_{1},$ where $0\leq f_{1}<1.$

Now let  $\left(15-\sqrt{220}\right)^{19} = f^{'}_{1},$ where $0< f^{'}_{1}<1.$

So $I_{1}+f_{1}+f_{1}^{'} = \left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{19}+\left(15-\sqrt{220}\right)^{19} = 10K$, where $K\in \mathbb{N}$

S0 $f_{1}+f^{'}_{1} = 10K-I\in \mathbb{N}$

But from above $0<\leq f_{1}+f^{'}_{1}<2$

So $f_{1}+f^{'}_{1} = 1$

So $I_{1}+0 = 10K-1$

Similarly Let $\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{82} = I_{2}+f_{2},$ where $0\leq f_{2}<1.$

Now let  $\left(15-\sqrt{220}\right)^{82} = f^{'}_{2},$ where $0< f^{'}_{2}<1.$

So $I_{2}+f_{2}+f_{2}^{'} = \left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{82}+\left(15-\sqrt{220}\right)^{82} = 10L$, where $L\in \mathbb{N}$

But from above $0<\leq f_{2}+f^{'}_{2}<2$

So $f_{2}+f^{'}_{2} = 1$

So $I_{2}+0 = 10L-1$

So $\lfloor \left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{19}+\left(15+\sqrt{220}\right)^{82} \rfloor = \lfloor I_{1}+f_{1}+I_{2}+f_{2}\rfloor = I_{1}+I_{2}+\lfloor f_{1}+f_{2} \rfloor $

$ = 10\left(K+L\right)-2+\lfloor f_{1}+f_{2} \rfloor $

Now I did not understand how can i solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea - but it's even less complicated than you think!

First, you've correctly noticed that $\big(15+\sqrt{220}\big)^{19}+\big(15-\sqrt{220}\big)^{19}$ is an integer that is a multiple of $10$. (Presumably you know this by taking the binomial expansion of both expressions and adding them together.) Similarly, $\big(15+\sqrt{220}\big)^{82}+\big(15-\sqrt{220}\big)^{82}$ is an integer that is a multiple of $10$.

On the other hand, $0<15-\sqrt{220}<1$, and in fact it's not hard to show that $0<15-\sqrt{220}<1/2.$ Therefore $0<\big(15-\sqrt{220}\big)^{19}+\big(15-\sqrt{220}\big)^{82}<1.$

The conclusion is that $\big(15+\sqrt{220}\big)^{19}+\big(15+\sqrt{220}\big)^{82}$ is a multiple of $10$ minus a positive real number that is less than $1$. In particular, its integer part must end in the digit $9$.

Comment: For the bounds for $15-\sqrt{220}$ note that $15-\sqrt{220}=\frac5{15+\sqrt{220}}\in(0,\frac5{29})\subset (0,\frac15)$.

Comment: Thanks Greg Martin and Hagen von Eitzen.